# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null

Tags: hyperlink, conflict

I have some scripts on my page that going in conflict.

Firebug gives me this error:

```
Failed to load 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
```

from this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jPrintArea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').click(function(){ $.jPrintArea('#tabella') });   
});
</script>
```

What is the problem?
Many thanks!

ps. sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.pack.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Always make sure you have the latest version of JQuery before attempting to debug. Odds are heavy this issue was fixed in the core library.

Answer (score 3):

It may also happen due to **conflicts**.

Use this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();    
j(document).ready(function(){
    j('.link').click(function(){ j.jPrintArea('#tabella') });    
});
```